# touch input : staying in horizontal drag (C#, xna/monogames for windows 8 app)

Tags: c#, windows-8, xna, touch, monogame

I'm making a game for windows 8 and I'm using touch input from xna framework. I would like to know if it's possible to stay in horizontal drag as long as I do not released my finger. As it works for now, if I press my finger on the screen and move to the right and keep my finger pressed, the player will just go right for like 1 second. I want it to go right as long as I keep my finger pressed.

Here is my code :

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        // read the next gesture
        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
        // has the user tapped the screen?
        switch (gesture.GestureType)
        {
            case GestureType.HorizontalDrag:
                if (gesture.delta.X > 0)
                    playerPosition.X += playerSpeed;
                else
                    playerPosition.X -= playerSpeed;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this logic,It might work

```
  ` bool IsDraging = false;
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (IsDraging)
        {
            MovePlayer();
        }
        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            // read the next gesture
            GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            // has the user tapped the screen?
            switch (gesture.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.HorizontalDrag:
                    IsDraging = true;
                    break;
                case GestureType.DragComplete: IsDraging = false; break;
            }
        }
    }
    void MovePlayer()
    {
        if (gesture.delta.X > 0)
            playerPosition.X += playerSpeed;
        else
            playerPosition.X -= playerSpeed;
    }
```